# Action View in android l

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an application with a search widget in the action bar. The application is not creating the search widget as an actionview when I switch the theme to use Material.Light in android L. When debugging I can see that the search view is null.

The menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/title"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

The creation of the menu:

```
 Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homescreen, menu);


    return true;

}
```

The initialization of a variable for the search view:

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Any ideas?

Update 1:
Ok so I stopped the app from crashing by replacing `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` with `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`. But now the search item shows up in the overflow menu rather than the action bar even though it is set to show as action always.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with setting it to show "always" and it ended up always being in the overflow. If you are using the support library make sure you are extending ActionBarActivity, if not, the regular Activity should work.